# Most efficient way to create object from text files in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, core-data, spreadsheet

What would be a convenient way to store text files, such that it would make it easy to create objects from them in iOS?

For example:

- spreadsheets -> XML -> NSObject subclass (the problem with this one is that Google Docs Spreadsheets can only be exported to OpenDocument Spreadsheets XML files, which are very inconvenient to parse)
- csv -> NSObject subclass (csv is too error-prone)

Sample data to be stored:

- Name - Number - Email
- Alice - 012345 - Alice@Alice.com
- Bob - 78910 - Bob@Bob.com

Sample class to be created:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *number;
    NSString *email;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I can't tell from your post if you are in control of the format of the files or not. Will the iOS app be responsible for authoring these files?

Comment: Yes, the files will be stored somewhere in the iOS bundle, and will have to be fetched and parsed by the iOS app.

Comment: So, the files are static for the life of the app? i.e. when you ship the app, the files are included with the app and will not change as the user uses the app?

Comment: Yes, the files are static. None of their content will have to be changed at runtime.

Comment: I just found a way to convert Google Spreadsheets-generated CSV files into a JSON format that seems quite convenient to parse. But any suggestion is still more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only have plaintext data here's what I would do:

1. Export spreadsheet to CSV.
2. Read CSV in python using CSV module.
3. Convert to an XML of your liking using minidom module.
4. Read the XML in Obj C. I used SMXML for this (https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument/). Not very fast but quite convenient.

This process can also be automated using AppleScript.

Comment: his solution sure involves a lot of work to go from one end to the other, but I'll consider it. Thank you very much.

Comment: doing this in python is actually quite a breeze, the minidom module is very easy to use while giving you maximum flexibility. Give it a shot.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "This solution". I'll look into it and let you know how that works for me. Thanks again.

Comment: I ended up using Spreadsheet -> CSV -> JSON -> NSDictionary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The preferred (and easy) way to do this in iOS is Property List (plist) files. Here is [Apple's entry documentation to plists](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)

They are essentially the JSON of iOS, and in fact you can easily convert between the two with NSJSONSerialization class methods.

This technique is congruent with how Apple does things (which is a win in the Apple dev community), and requires no external libraries. Additionally, there is built in support all over the place for writing plists back out, should you decide to expand the app in the future.

It should be mentioned, though, that to get actual custom objects (that is, instances of custom classes) from a file, you need to explore the slightly more complex world of [object archiving](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would I have to keep a plist file for each instance of my class? By looking at the plist file of my app, it seems to me plist files are similar to dictionaries, in the way they associate a value to a key. If so, I can't see how I would store all the instances of my class within one plist file. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Much like JSON, a plist file supports NSString, NSData, NSNumber, NSDate, NSDictionary, and—last but not least—NSArray.  Thus you can store arrays of objects in a plist file.

Comment: plist files are almost exactly as useful as JSON (They're just a different syntax (in XML) for the same basic structures). They are as flexible as you build them to be. Essentially, any [] in your JSON would be an NSArray, and {} would be an NSDictionary, 1234 = NSNumber, "hello" = NSString, etc... And the collections (arrays and dictionaries) can hold other collections... it's *just like* JSON this way, but a format which the Cocoa Frameworks have been designed to work with for many years.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really elegant solution and you can use whatever type of file you want, use a plist and make it possible to convert your classes/instances into property list object using the initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder: methods in the NSCoding protocol.